# Partial View not binding with the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have main view binding to custom model with two partial views. One partial view is binding to schedule model and other to the same custom model.

The second partial view is showing null on http posting.

This is the Main View

```
@model DBS.CustomVariable

<div id="divSchedule" style="display: none" align="left">
            @Html.Partial("_cron", new DBS.Schedule2())
            @Html.Partial("ScheduleEditPartial" ,Model)
</div>
```

The view model is like this

```
namespace DBS
{
    public class CustomVariable
    {
        public int ReportId { get; set; }

        public string ReportName { get; set; }

        public string ReportTypeId { get; set; }

        public string TemplateLocation { get; set; }

        public bool IsScheduled { get; set; }

        public int ScheduleID { get; set; }

        public string MailCC { get; set; }

        public string MailBCC { get; set; }

        public string MailSubject { get; set; }

        public string MailBody { get; set; }

        public string MailTo { get; set; }

        public bool Status { get; set; }

        public bool IsReportNameOverwrite { get; set; }

        public string NamingConvention { get; set; }

        public string FileAttribs { get; set; }

        public string[] DirectoryName { get; set; }

        public List<string> FolderName { get; set; }

        public string SavePath { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", ErrorMessage = "Please start with alphabets followed by alphanumeric or _.")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public string DefaultLocation => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultExcelReportSavePath"];

        public int ShareOption { get; set; }

        public string[] station_arr { get; set; }

        public string TemplateOriginalName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the controller is this

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "ExcelCreate")]
    [SessionExpireFilter]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form, HttpPostedFileBase file, CustomVariable modelCustomVariable)
    {......}
```

I am getting null values in the customvariable in controller method.

Where am i missing?

Comment: Is `modelCustomVariable` coming from that second partial view? If so, you need to add its code to the post. It is also not clear how are you actually doing the posting

Comment: @Andrei I found the solution. I was doing a post in Partial view as well.  I removed the line and its working fine

Comment: glad you solved it. Consider either posting a self answer if you can explain it so that other may benefit, or removing the post if it is too specific